# Accessibility of deleting list items

Tags: html, wcag2.0

I am working with accessibility on a webpage and I came across this which I could not find an answer for. Given that I have a list of items and the option to delete each item by clicking on a trash icon next to the item (See attached image), how can i ensure that assistive technologies such as screen readers (JAWS) can properly relate each trash icon with the right item.

This relates to WCAG 2.0:
[1.3.1 Info and Relationships: Information, structure, and relationships conveyed through presentation can be programmatically determined or are available in text. (Level A)](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-programmatic.html)

The code could be something like this:

```
<ol>
<li id="item-1">Item-1</li>
<li id="item-2">Item-2</li>
<li id="item-3">Item-3</li>
</ol>

<a id="a1" onclick="removeItem('item-1');" title="Delete item"><img alt="Delete item" src="trash.gif"></a>
<a id="a2" onclick="removeItem('item-2');" title="Delete item"><img alt="Delete item" src="trash.gif"></a>
<a id="a3" onclick="removeItem('item-2');" title="Delete item"><img alt="Delete item" src="trash.gif"></a>
```

[A list with 3 items. Each item can be deleted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WZXs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you use AngularJS, it is pretty simple

```
<ol>
<li id="item-1" ng-show="isEnabled(1)">Item-1</li>
<li id="item-2" ng-show="isEnabled(2)">Item-2</li>
<li id="item-3" ng-show="isEnabled(3)">Item-3</li>
</ol>

<a id="a1" ng-click="disable(1)" title="Delete item"><img alt="Delete item" src="trash.gif"></a>
<a id="a2" ng-click="disable(2)" title="Delete item"><img alt="Delete item" src="trash.gif"></a>
<a id="a3" ng-click="disable(3)" title="Delete item"><img alt="Delete item" src="trash.gif"></a>
```

Insert a proper `ng-controller` according to your needs, and set a flag variable to check if a list item has been deleted.

**disable(x)** set that flag to false for item with ID x
**isEnabled(x)** returns true if the flag is true

PS. you will have to code these functiond

Comment: My question is not about how i can delete an item. It is about how a screen reader can know that "trash icon a1" will delete item-1. Sure it is easy for us to see because they are on same row but blind people/screen readers need this information programmatically. For form items we can use label with for attribute to programmatically identify a label to an input field. How can i programmatically identify trash icon a1 with item-1?